# Is decision tree regression with AdaBoost possible in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

Scikit-learn (Python) has AdaBoostRegressor that can be used *e.g.* with DecisionTreeRegressor. Does R have the corresponding implementation, *i.e.* AdaBoost for regression?

I would be interested in applying RWeka's M5P as the base leaner for AdaBoost in R.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper, I came to conclusion that currently there is no (at least publicly available) implementation of AdaBoost.R2 (i.e. AdaBoost for regression) for R.

Good news is that there is at least one gradient booster in R also applicable for regression: *xgboost* (objective = 'reg:linear'). However, it can use only the predefined boosters: *gbtree*, *gblinear* or *dart*, and no other base classifiers or regressors can be provided for the algorithm.